# Calling click event doesn't submit form with Ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm calling the click event with `<button type="action" value="click"></button>` to submit a form with Ajax. To submit form with button type `submit` works if I don't call the `click` event. So you can eliminate this possibility. I just need to call the `submit` function with click event which I doubt I've proceed it right.

**The buggy code example:**

```
// On document ready
$(function() {
  $('#update-button').click(function(){
    $('#update-cart').submit(function(ev) {

      // Prevent the form from actually submitting
      ev.preventDefault();
      // Get the post data
      var data = $(this).serialize();

      // Send it to the server
      $.post('/', data, function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (response.success) {
        // YES
        } else {
        // Ooo NO
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  As you have it now, when you click on `#update-button`, what it does it *bind* an submit event to `#update-cart`.  Also I don't think `type="action"` is valid HTML.  You probably want `type="submit"` or `type="button"`.

Comment: Have you assigned 'id' to your button i.e update-button ???

Comment: @AkshayChawla Yes I did. I think it has to do something with javascript.

Comment: try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/zj39mLq2/

Comment: @AkshayChawla I'm on to that and I have tried that. Still not submitted.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zj39mLq2/1/ how about this?

Comment: @AkshayChawla Yes.That is exactly what I did but still I couldn't see the expected result. So I've logged the process to console and I found out that the click event wasn't fired. I had one hidden input field with `id="update-button"`. So You can post the answer. I'm glad you've helped! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// On document ready
$(function() {
  $('#update-button').click(function(event){
      // Prevent the form from actually submitting
      event.preventDefault();
      // Get the post data
      var data = $("#update-cart").serialize();

     // Send it to the server
     $.post('/', data, function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       if (response.success) {
         // YES
       } else {
         // Ooo NO
      }
    });
  });
});
```

To avoid same `id` issues which take a hell lot of time to solve, its better to give proper naming conventions to DOM element.

- Hidden field -> hdnElementName
- Button -> btnElementName
- Textbox -> txtElementName

Using such naming conventions will surely remove such mistakes. :)